# Get datatable's binded backing bean data from external javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

In my backing bean I have a list which is binded to the datatable. I need to get this list data(*called **routes***) inside an external javascript.

**Backing Bean**

```
@Component("routeBean")
@Scope("session")
public class RouteBean {

    List<RouteModel> routes;
    private RouteModel routeModel;

    public List<RouteModel> getRoutes() {
        return routes;
    }

    public void setRoutes(List<RouteModel> routes) {
        this.routes = routes;
    }

    public void addToList(){
        routes.add(getRouteModel());
        setRouteModel(new RouteModel());
    }

    public RouteModel getRouteModel() {
        return routeModel;
    }

    public void setRouteModel(RouteModel routeModel) {
        this.routeModel = routeModel;
    }
            .......................
}
```

**Jsf**

```
<p:fieldset legend="routeFieldset">
    <p:inputText id="txtKm" value="#{routeBean.routeModel.km}"/><br/>
    <p:commandButton value="Route Toevoegen" id="btnSaveRoute"
                                 action="#{routeBean.addToList}"
                                 update="routeListPanelGroup"
                                 oncomplete="showBeanData()"/> <!-- this will execute the javascript method and show the data -->
</p:fieldset>
<p:fieldset legend="Routelijst">
    <h:panelGroup id="routeListPanelGroup">                              
        <p:dataTable value="#{routeBean.routes}"
                     var="route" id="routeListDTable"
                     widgetVar="routeWidget">

            <p:column headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value="#{route.id}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Km">
                <h:outputText value="#{route.km}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</p:fieldset>
    .......................
```

**External Javascript**

```
function showBeanData(){
    alert(backing bean data -> routes); //??????
}
```

So, when user clicks on the '*btnSaveRoute*' the new object is added to '**routes**' list(*this works fine*). And after this a javascript method must get me the '**routes**' inside the external javascript without using hidden fields?

*Note: I'm using primefaces*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read PrimeFaces's documentation on `RequestContext`. The showcase is [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/requestContext.jsf).

Basically, the idea is you can send data from your backing bean to the client side using the method `#RequestContext.addCallbackParam()`. On the client side, execute the `handleComplete(xhr, status, args)` at `oncomplete` and get your data from the `args`.

Comment: I couldn't manage to add this to my situation. What I've done is: In routeBean at end of the the _addToList_ method  `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("routes", routes);` , in javascript `function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) { alert(args.routes.toSource()); }`, in jsf in the _commandButton_ `oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)"`. I get ({empty:false}) as result via de javascript. Could you please show it on my codes?

Comment: `routes` is returned as a JSON object. For example, if you return a `User` object with `Firstname` property, in the JavaScript, you can get the firstname using `args.user.firstname`. If I'm not wrong, the `toSource()` function is a function you wrote on the server side. Hence, the client side cannot know how to execute it. Just play with it for a while. I think you'll eventually figure out how to get the list data out of the `args.routes`. Try `alert(args.routes)` to confirm the data is there.

Comment: In the `addToList` method inside the bean I've converted the `routes` to json by using Gson. The code: `RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(); Gson gson = new Gson(); requestContext.addCallbackParam("routes", gson.toJson(routes));`. In the javascript I've decoded the coming `routes` parameter. The code: `var json = JSON.parse(args.routes);`. This decoded json string can now be looped by a for loop and transfered to an array. Thank you!